# Algorithm - comparing performance

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have 3 algoithrms A,B and C to process n records.

```
algorithm A takes 80n + 40 steps
algorithm B takes n^2 + 30n steps
algorithm C takes 2^n steps
```

Decide which algorithms is most efficient when performing

```
i)  10 < n < 50
```

The way I would solve this problem is by assuming n is equals to a value for example

for i) Assume that n = 20

so

```
algo A - 80(20) + 40 = 1640  steps
algo B - 20^2 = 400 steps
algo C - 2^20 = 1048576 steps
```

therefore algo B is most efficent.

I am not really sure whether I have evaluated the 3 algorithms performance correctly because I am just substituting a n with a value instead of using Big O notation?

Please advise. thanks

Comment: Big O gives a theoretical limit. Actual implementations can have big constants, and for small problem size, a `O(n)` algorithm might be slower than a `O(n^2)` algorithm.

Comment: If you want to compare small problem size, use the total Time complexity, not the asymptotic representation, and make sure you use a fair standard to follow in what accounts as an operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big-O notation deals with n that is arbitrary large, i.e. in order to evaluate O(n) the expression should be calculated for n-->infinity. In your case n is given, thus the overall running time can be precisely calculated, exactly the way you did it.